# What does this diagram with two opposing arrows depict?

Tags: relay, timer, normally-open

I have an astronomical timer relay that controls lights.  Its user manual shows this diagram:

[image]

What do the opposing fat arrows (vertically aligned) indicate?  How would one read them?  Also, it seems like there are three switches to the far right (within the load being controlled I presume).  What do they signify?

While they may be good for professionals, for an end-user, such diagrams are somewhat meaningless, I feel.

PS: When I asked the manufacturer why output #1 was not used, they told me to ignore it, that it was 'normally open' and that they put it in because some customers wanted that option.  How do those customers use the product?

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to the customers you refer to? Can you speak with them? Is that at all possible do you think? Output #1 is not normally open BTW.

Comment: @Andyaka No, I'm afraid not.  BTW, the person I talked to at their tech. support did not sound too knowledgeable, so that information may well be suspect.

Comment: In the day follow lighth arrow, so contacts 2 and 3 closed. Dark time the black arrow, 2 and 1 closed. My guess, it is not standard pictogram.

Comment: Strange. I interpret it as a standard SPDT.

Comment: @Antonio51 Thanks, I have that document.  I know how to program and use the device.  Rather, my question is about the diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Also, it seems like there are three switches to the far right (within the load being controlled I presume.) What do they signify?

The small relay shown on the right side of the image - note the dark side is going to LINE and light side is going to NEUTRAL, to indicate polarity.  Typically, this would be a three-phase contactor.  When this timer activates, this contactor is switched on, supplying three-phase power to the designated load.  It is small and nondescript because they are speculating about what you actually will have wired here.

> What do the opposing fat arrows (vertically aligned) indicate?

The dark arrow on the A1-A2 side of the contact is indicating that it is the source of the action; the source of the magnetic field, pulling on the  contact it points to.

The light arrow on the 1-2-3 contact indicates it is the target of the magnetic field.  Normally 1-2 is connected, and when it is pulled towards the coil, 2-3 connect.

It looks like there is a C1 and C2 set of outputs.  So could switch two independent contactors (say, one for 480VAC, and another for 240VAC power, simultaneously.)

> When I asked the manufacturer why output #1 was not used, they told me to ignore it, that it was 'normally open' and that they put it in because some customers wanted that option. How do those customers use the product?

There are many possibilities.  For a darkroom, consider if two contactors were connected to terminal 1 (timer off-state) and terminal 3 (timer on-state.)  When the timer was off, regular room lighting was active.  When the timer was activated, the regular room lights shut off, and instead a very low-power red light is activated, to not interfere with developing the photos.  After a few hours (film is developed) regular lights come back on automatically.

Comment: Sorry can only upvote once! :)
I am controlling two LED lights wired in parallel, through a single output (C1).  Those lights total about 24 Watts.  I am thinking that I don't have to use a contactor.  I'd appreciate it you'd verify this.  Thanks regards.

Comment: The darkroom example is excellent thanks.

Comment: The capacity (amperage) of the contacts is usually printed on the unit, such as "480VAC, 1A" or "240VAC, 2.5A non-inductive, 500W" or similar.  If nothing like this is printed, this information should be in the manual or datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

The DTR-20/20M is an electronic timer with a real time clock.

It has two independent programmable channels, each with its own output relay (C1 & C2).

The diagram in question shows the power supply input / relay contacts for one channel, wired to energise the coil of the external three phase contactor. The opposing white and black arrows indicate contact closure and opening when the relay coil is energised / de-energised.

Here's the overall schematic.

[image]

The 'NC' contact of relay C1 is not used.

Output C2 is not shown.

Comment: Many thanks, regards.

Comment: Anytime, Sabuncu!